# AttributeError: Window1 instance has no attribute 'master'

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am new to OOP so bear with me...I have googled solutions to this very basic error but can't figure it out. 
I just want to click the "OK" button to destroy the window.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window1:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.button1=Button(master,text="OK",command=self.button_click)
        self.button1.pack()


    def button_click(self):
        self.master.destroy()


def main():
    root=Tk()
    app=Window1(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is actually very simple: you just need to make `master` an attribute of `Window1`.

Add this line:

```
self.master=master
```

to the top of `Window1.__init__`:

```
def __init__(self,master):
    ####################
    self.master=master
    ####################
    self.button1=Button(master,text="OK",command=self.button_click)
    self.button1.pack()
```

Now, `master` will be an attribute of `Window1` and you can access it through `self` via `self.master`

Comment: Thanks for your help, you have no idea how long I was searching for a solution.